# RM jar file log4j vulnerable version

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, build.gradle

At the moment I am trying to find a quick solution to fix log4j vulnerability without changing to an updated version of log4j. My gradle project uses the application plugin to build a jar file. As part of the runtime transitive dependencies, I end up pulling in org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12.
I want to continue using the vulnerable version of log4j however remove the JMS appender file from the JAR to mitigate the issue.

I can locate the file on my local machine and do this however I want a way that will work more seamlessly for others working on the code…
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain why you don’t want to update, and want to instead carry out operations that may well result in runtime problems - leaving you potentially vulnerable to DoS attacks?

Comment: We cannot risk having the code not working as there are other projects depending on it which are out of our control and so before they upgrade, we want a quick temporary fix.

Comment: If it’s a library why does it depend on Log4j2-core at all??

Comment: It’s a relative new library so we have used this for testing purposes as well as keeping track of data flow.